# Need my .html signautre in my emails: not working

Tags: email-signature

I have the below link for my email signature but i can't seem to get it installed via thunderbird. I'm fine via my gmail account settings but not in thunderbird. Can anyone help me?

file:///Users/victoria/Downloads/index-1.html

Answer (score 0):

To quote from [Mozilla's help page](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/signatures):

> One way to create a signature file is by using the Thunderbird
>   composer. As an example, create a new HTML-formatted message in
>   Thunderbird (File > New > Message). Make sure that the formatting
>   toolbar is displayed.
>
> HtmlToolbar (If it is not displayed, you are composing a message
>   formatted in text, not HTML. To change to HTML, select Options >
>   Delivery Format > Rich Text (HTML) Only.)
>
> Compose and format your signature as desired. Note that numerous
>   formatting functions are available from the Insert and Format menus.
>
> https://prod-cdn.sumo.mozilla.net/uploads/gallery/images/2011-03-14-10-08-08-9612b4.jpg Click File >
>   Save As > File. Make sure "HTML files" is selected, and then specify a
>   file name and click Save. Close the message window and discard the
>   message without saving. Open the Account Settings and select the email
>   account in the panel on the left. Check Attach the signature from a
>   file, click Choose and navigate to the file you created.